# Order of instantiation of Android Content Providers

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

For my application I need to have one Content Provider started before anything else. As far as I can tell the order is independent from the order in the AndroidManifest and is not alphabetical.

How can I control the order in which Android calls the onCreate() methods of the Content Providers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `android:initOrder` attribute. Below is what Android docs says

**android:initOrder**
The order in which the content provider should be instantiated, relative to other content providers hosted by the same process. When there are dependencies among content providers, setting this attribute for each of them ensures that they are created in the order required by those dependencies. The value is a simple integer, with higher numbers being initialized first.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#init

Comment: Thanks. I even had the documentation right in front of me and didn't see the initOrder attribute...